# How to Push Maven Project With Modules Using Git?

Tags: java, git, maven

I would like to know that if I have following project structure:

```
main project (parent)
|--pom.xml
sub project (module 1)
|--pom.xml
sub project 2 (module 2)
|--pom.xml
```

Is it possible to push to repository all changes with their current structure by only applying push command to parent project? Would it be also wise to do so? If not, then why? Would it be better to push each of those project individually?

Comment: You could just write a script.  I'm not sure what this has to do with Maven.

Comment: It has to do because my project is built with Maven. What I wanted is to that if I make some changes in modules and then when I want to push to my repository I don't have to push each module individually which is quiet tedious. If I don't have other option, then I have to push every module when I make some changes to them.

Comment: But you'll need to commit each of the changes as well, so it's not just about pushing.  If you want all of your subprojects to act as if they were in one repo, why don't you just put them all in one repo?

Comment: That's the idea and that's what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simpler than I thought. When you have other sub projects it is very important to add them under your main project folder. Now that I have added sub projects folders under main project folder it automatically recognized them as a new change in the project thus whenever you make any changes in your sub projects you can simply push your main project to get nice and clean project structure in your repository.

For example:

Main project folder name: myApp
Sub project A folder name: subProjectA
Sub project B folder name: subProjectB

Clean and good folder structure would be in this case:

myApp/subProjectA/ and myApp/subProjectB/. With this way you can push your changes with simple push and you don't have to push every time each project when you make changes to them.